# Hide status output from jq in dos/windows

Tags: json, batch-file, curl, jq

I'm using curl for windows (http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/) in conjunction with jq (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to interact with a web api via a batch file.  The seemingly simple problem I'm having is that no matter what I do, I cannot seem to suppress JQ's "status" output.  In particular, it always outputs "progress status," like:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   116  100    99  100    17    908    155 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   908
```

A simplified example batch file would be:

```
@echo off
@curl.exe -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"cmd\":\"login\"}' http://localhost:80/json | jq -r .session > sess.txt
```

Note that jq does operate as expected - I simply need to get it to operate *silently*.  It seems to ignore @echo off, and I couldn't find any switches in the manual to disable this output.

Any ideas...?

Thanks much in advance :)

Comment: if this is printed in stderr it can be redirected with `2>nul`

Comment: `curl.exe -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{\"cmd\":\"login\"}' http://localhost:80/json | jq -r .session 2> nul` still shows it...

Comment: what about `1>nul 2>nul`?

Comment: That looks like it's output from calling curl. Redirect stderr for _that_.

Comment: Jeff: That's it!  Duh, how could I not have noticed :D  Please submit an answer, & I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
curl --silent
```

```
-s, --silent
  Silent or quiet mode. Do not show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl
  mute.
```

- [Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/4e0992f8c1d6ed7571c0f27be1a/ff-song.sh#L100)
- [explainshell.com - curl --silent](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl+--silent)

Comment: probably want to use `--silent` in combination with `--show-error`, otherwise if there's a connection error or whatever, you won't get any error notice from curl

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: In order to remove the progress bar on curl restful api response ,Use the `--silent` flag (in short `-s`) or use `--no-progress-meter`. I suggest using the latter because you'd like to get warnings and informational messages on bad responses.

**examples**:

1.
`curl -s <Web-Address>` OR `curl --silent <Web-Address>`

2.
 `curl --no-progress-meter <Web-Address>`

For more [**Curl Documentation**](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-s)

```
-s, --silent

Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. 
Makes Curl mute. 
It will still output the data you ask for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.

Use -S, --show-error in addition to this option to disable progress meter but still show error messages.

--no-progress-meter

Option to switch off the progress meter output without muting or otherwise affecting warning and informational messages like -s, --silent does.

Note that this is the negated option name documented. You can thus use --progress-meter to enable the progress meter again.
```